# pandas read csv use delimiter for a fixed amount of time

Tags: python, pandas, csv, logging

Suppose I have a log file structured as follow for each line:

```
$date $machine $task_name $loggedstuff
```

I hope to read the whole thing with `pd.read_csv('blah.log', sep=r'\s+')`. The problem is, `$loggedstuff` has spaces in it, is there any way to limit the delimiter to operate exactly 3 times so everything in `loggedstuff` will appear in the dataframe as a single column?

I've already tried using `csv` to parse it as list of list and then feed it into pandas, but that is slow, I'm wondering if there's a more direct way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Are the columns separated by a single space?

Comment: @Alex yes. `\s+` is probably not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can read each line of the csv file as a single string, then convert the resulted dataframe to 3 columns by regular expression.

```
df = pd.read_csv('./test.csv', sep='#', squeeze=True)
df = df.str.extract('([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(.+)')
```

in which you can change the separator to whatever not appeared in the document.

Comment: This works, I'm using `df.str.split(' ', 3, expand=True)` and it's working perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

#### Setup

*tmp.txt*

```
a b c d
1 2 3 test1 test2 test3
1 2 3 test1 test2 test3 test4
```

#### Code

```
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.txt', sep='\n', header=None)
cols = df.loc[0].str.split(' ')[0]
df = df.drop(0)

def splitter(s):
    vals = s.iloc[0].split(' ')
    d = dict(zip(cols[:-1], vals))
    d[cols[-1]] = ' '.join(vals[len(cols) - 1: ])
    return pd.Series(d)

df.apply(splitter, axis=1)
```

returns

```
   a  b  c                        d
1  1  2  3        test1 test2 test3
2  1  2  3  test1 test2 test3 test4
```

Comment: This generates `CParser error` because the number of columns is not the same and the first column doesn't have the most spaces. Sorry the original problem was phrased in the wrong way, edited.

Comment: This works, but it's slower than directly using `str.split()` because `apply` is not vectorized.

Answer (score 2):

When using `expand=True`, the split elements will expand out into separate columns.

Parameter n can be used to limit the number of splits in the output.

Details about the same cane [From pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Pattern to use

> df.str.split(pat=None, n=-1, expand=False) 
>   expand : bool, default False
>
> Expand the splitted strings into separate columns.
>
> If True, return DataFrame/MultiIndex expanding dimensionality.
>
> If  False, return Series/Index, containing lists of strings

```
df.str.split(' ', n=3, expand=True)
```